# Passing in number of iterations into jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In JMeter it is possible for me to specify the number of threads for a test in the command line. I just do:

```
jmeter -n -t mytest.jmx -l output.jtl -j jmeterlog.log -Jthreads=5
```

Is it possible to do something similar for number of iterations?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you just use [_P](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the loop count.

> EXAMPLE
>
> Define the property value:
>
> jmeter -Jgroup1.threads=7 -Jhostname1=www.realhost.edu
>
> Fetch the values:
>
> ${__P(group1.threads)} - return the value of group1.threads
>
> ${__P(group1.loops)} - return the value of group1.loops
>
> ${__P(hostname,www.dummy.org)} - return value of property hostname or www.dummy.org if not defined